# Setting up Apache server on Kali Linux to limit number of concurrent connections

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, connection

I've attempted the following command:
`apache2 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT`

However, I realized that the command only handles socket connections. I need to locate the Apache server parameter that accepts a number of concurrent connections, and then modify it.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? In general Apache is an “on request” server; no persistent connections. So look at the `KeepAlive` and `MaxKeepAliveRequests` settings as well as the `prefork.c` stuff like `ServerLimit` and `MaxClients` as well as `MaxRequestsPerChild`. Apache seems tough but balance those settings and you should be good.

Comment: All the above and you probably shouldn't be using Kali.